# Configuring IIS Express fails with configuration file error

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I got this error when I created a website in Visual Studio 2013:

```
File name: redirection.config

Error: Cannot read configuration file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue could not even start a web project in vs 2013
So i tried the following

[Unable to create a new web project in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582929/unable-to-create-a-new-web-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue in visual-studio 2015. Tried many solutions, used Process Monitor to identify a missing directory structure, copied the 'config' folder -

`C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\` -> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\`

Also using the change `iis` express user home fix -

eg. `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe /userhome:c:\temp\iisexpress`

Need to delete existing iisexpress folder, usually in `[home]\documents` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I looked in the file, and it was corrupted, only filled with `NUL`.

Fortunately I was able to recover the same file from my old PC:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="configurationRedirection" />
    </configSections>
    <configProtectedData>
        <providers>
            <add name="IISRsaProvider" type="" description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt" keyContainerName="iisConfigurationKey" cspProviderName="" useMachineContainer="true" useOAEP="false" />
        </providers>
    </configProtectedData>
    <configurationRedirection />
</configuration>
```

Probably you can even leave the providers tag empty.