# Cannot read configuration file in visual studio, can this be fixed

Tags: visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I trying to use Visual Studio as I required to learn .NET and visual studio as part of new job. Normally I program everything in Notepad++ (PHP/javascript) because it just works fine for me.

I have been on for three days trying to install Visual Studio, finally got it to install with the components required, as you can imagine my experience so far of Visual Studio is not too great.

Sound cliche but following a nice simple [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc) to get the basics out of the way, as you do.

When I click to debug or the IIS Express button I am greeted with this error.

[image]

I have tried restarting the project

I have tried restarting Visual Studio

No matter how many projects I create I get the same error.

I have been trying to fix this for hours now, I have turned on [IIS in windows features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901434/iis-manager-in-windows-10). I am missing something, do I need to un intall wampp (which isnt actually running)?
The folder I create has no permissions and is accessible however the read only box is always ticked even if I uncheck this and apply settings.

I have tried manually creating a site in [IIS manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQgbOIjWgBs), and again I get this error on authorization.

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make
>   sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the
>   physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the
>   application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has Read access to the physical path.
>   Then test these settings again.

Any help would be amazing as I'm pulling my hair out here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create a new web project in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582929/unable-to-create-a-new-web-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to file rights.  I have run into this when I am trying to run my code that lives on a network share, or more commonly when it is living on the host and I am running Windows in a Virtual Machine. I would confirm that you have sufficient disk space, the code is living on a local drive, that the folder is not read-only and that the running user has rights to write to that folder.

It looks like you are running from a folder on your Desktop folder. This should be fine. If you got that code from a Git server sometimes the files come down as read-only. I would confirm that the "Current Work" folder is *not* read-only nor are any of its children.  I would also go into the Security tab of the folder's properties in Explorer and grant "Everyone" full control (probably safe since this is just a developer environment).  Test after each of these.